# Jquery Ajax HTML - Add Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried this code locally and I can't seem to get it to display the contents of the html file in my country_slide div. I've tried playing around with it a bit all to no avail. I can't seem to see any code to actually tell the ajax where to put the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uhEgG/23/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("country_link");
    a.onclick = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").show();
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two questions here it seems, which is it? Are you trying to display a loading variable or trying to display the result data when the request completes?

Comment: You're mixing and matching JQuery, which is not invalid, but it is odd. Are you sure that there are no Javascript errors occuring?

Comment: Sorry I have clarified my question now

Comment: In your JSFiddle example, `div#country_slide` has no content, and therefore `show` will display nothing. Not to mention that it is visible by default. You must be looking for something along the lines of `TGH`'s answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually insert the content into the parent element using the .html function

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("country_link");
    a.onclick = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way the spinner can initially be placed inside the parent, and then be overwritten when the content is returned from the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSend` and `complete` methods to show or hide the loading symbol

```
beforeSend : function() {
   $('.loader').show();
}, 
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    $("#country_slide").show();
    alert('request successful');
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('request failed');
},
complete : function() {
   $('.loader').hide();
},
```